# Path not accesible in Django

Tags: html, css, django

This is maybe a very silly doubt, but i can't seem to figure out the reason for my code not working. So this is my Django Project file directory structure.

[image]

Now, my targeted HTML file (index.html) is in **aboutme/templates/** folder. I want to render it from the view.py in my aboutme app. Now my css and js files are inside **"assets"** folder which will be used by my index.html. But when i run the server the CSS files are not taking any effect on my index.html page. I have added the static files path in my settings.py of my project and added the static path in my index.html while trying to refer to the CSS and JS files, but still the changes are not reflected in the html file.

Below is the snippet of my settings.py file:

[image]

And below is the snippet of the index.html file from where i am trying to access the CSS files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the CSS in the html using `{% load static %}` tag.
Also use the URL dynamically, like so:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```